# How to avoid thicker border width in excel , SSRRS Report?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, report

In my SSRS report when i give the border as 'Solid', it gives a thicker border in its excel version than the excels normal border width. Did any one come across a situation like this. What is the possible solution to avoid this.

Please, I would appreciate all your help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Suni

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we ran into this problem as well.  1pt "Solid" borders are 20-foot thick walls in Excel, good for repelling barbarian invaders and Tidal Waves.  We solved this by setting border width to .5pt, "solid".  That produced the results we wanted ("average" width borderline, more or less) in Excel, and it still looked fine in the actual report (and when printed, I'll note).